# ffmpeg: Perform filter at only 1 audio stream, recoding other stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a mp4 video file with 2 audio streams. Both at e-ac3. I want the first stream recode to ac3, the other to aac. If I perform a filter for the 2nd stream, it seems ffmpeg performs it at both streams, but the first stream should be left alone - only recoded to ac3

I use following in a cmd file to batch it at my videos :

```
set tstLen=
rem set tstLen=-to 180

set audParam=-ac 2 -af "aresample=matrix_encoding=dplii,loudnorm=I=-16:LRA=11:TP=-1.5" -ar 48000 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k
%pathToFFMPeG% -hide_banner -y %tstLen% -i %1 -map 0:a:1 %audParam% "Y:\_\ToDo\%~n1.m4a"

set audParam=-c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 448k -c:a:1 copy
set audDefault=-disposition:a:0 default -disposition:a:1 none
%pathToFFMPeG% -hide_banner -y %tstLen% -i %1 -i "Y:\_\ToDo\%~n1.m4a" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 1 -c:v copy %audParam% %audDefault% "Y:\_\ToDo\%~nx1"
```

Currently I need to create a m4a file containing only the stream I want it to be in aac, afterwards I encode the mp4 where the 1st stream is encoded to ac3 and injecting the m4a into it. The filter also will do a normalisation of the audio, and I don't want it to perform at the 1st audio stream.

Is there a way to perform these tasks in 1 command, so I don't have to first create a m4a?

I tried with following code :

```
set tstLen=
rem set tstLen=-to 180

set audParam=-c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 448k -ac:a:1 2 -af:a:1 "aresample=matrix_encoding=dplii,loudnorm=I=-16:LRA=11:TP=-1.5" -ar:a:1 48000 -c:a:1 libfdk_aac -b:a:1 192k
set audDefault=-disposition:a:0 default -disposition:a:1 none
%pathToFFMPeG% -hide_banner -y %tstLen% -i %1 -map 0 -c:v copy %audParam% %audDefault% "Y:\_\ToDo\%~nx1"
```

But with this code also the first stream gets normalised and even the "dolby pro logic II" resample filter will be performed at the 1st stream, which it should't.

NB : the %tstLen% code is for making a test of about 3 minutes to see if the result is what I wants it to be, while performing the filter in the 1st task can take some time.

Comment: use `-filter:a:1` instead `-af:a:1`

Comment: Tx. Баяр Гончикжапов, your answer did it.